# Is rank requirements only for getting items, or for using them as well, on Vanguard, Crucible and Eris?

Tags: destiny

For some items on vendors where there is a rank requirement before I can purchase the item, does this rank requirement apply to:

- Only purchasing the item
- Both purchasing and using the item

---

**Background**

I am playing a level 31 Warlock. I want to do the Nightfall, Weekly, etc. more than once each week and get rewards.

If I create another Warlock, level him up to 20, can I then shuffle all my gear from my current one onto the new one and level him instantly up to level 31, with good weapons to boot?

I ask because for this new character, some of the gear will have been bought on vendors where there was a rank requirement, like getting Crucible vendor to rank 3 before I can purchase weapons, as an example. Will such a weapon be usable at all on this new character with his lower rank on said vendor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weapons and armour items have no rank requirements on them. Many of the items you can get versions of by chance through cryptarch level up packages and such like and are variants on what the vanguard vendor (for example) sells.

A concrete example of the rank requirements at work is that Iron Banner reputation reset at the beginning of the last tournament. All items I bought (shader, cloak, emblem, scout rifle) were still usable even after the reset.

I have not done explicit tests on the exact scenario that you are describing but given weapons don't specify the level requirements I would be 99.9% confident that you are fine doing what you want to do.

Personally I am more of a fan of variety though and like having different classes. Weapons can still be passed between and that goes a long way. For the maximum grind efficiency though doing what you suggest is what I have heard a lot of other people talk about doing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really want to set aside enough time to really maintain 2 or 3 characters on all fronts. I could still shuffle weapons back and forth, but there's a lot of grinding involved in getting a character to level 31, I don't want to set aside that time again for this.

Comment: Yeah. My other characters are lower level which is why I called out that its not as efficient for grinding. The amount of damn shards I'd need to level up armour on three characters for level 31 would just make me want to cry. I'm having enough trouble getting them all for just one character (I know, need to raid more).